# git mv then push question

Tags: git

Wondering why I can't push to origin.  Here's step by step...

```
git clone git@github.com:globegit/aRepository.git
cd aRepository
git branch --track mymaster master
git checkout master
git mv oldfile newfile

git status  
- On branch mymaster
- Changes to be committed:
-   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
-
-   renamed:    oldfile -> newfile
-
git commit -m 'renamed a file'

git status  
- On branch mymaster
- Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.  
-  
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Fine and dandy, but then why can't I push out this change to remote?

Is a git-mv not considered a change, so it figures I'm up to date even
with a new commit object?

```
git push  
Everything up-to-date  
git push origin master  
Everything up-to-date
```

Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You've committed changes to a branch (`mymaster`) that has no remote tracking branch, while your branch which is tracking a remote (`master` and `origin/master` respectively) has no changes.

You'll have to merge your changes into `master` before you can push them to `origin/master`, or push your `mymaster` branch to the server.

So either:

```
git checkout master
git merge mymaster
git push
```

or

```
git push --set-upstream origin mymaster
```

Comment: I guess my confusion is partly to do with what the "master" branch that gets created with a clone is for.  I thought of it as an alias to origin/master, or if not an alias, is a tracking branch of origin/master, so my mymaster tracking branch is tracking master and it's tracking master/origin.. so everything should just flow on through.  Guess not.  So really the master branch is a defaulted gift and set up as a tracker of origin/master, me thinks.  Thanks for you answer!!

Comment: When you create a new branch, it doesn't track anything by default. The concept of "pushing" isn't about merging changes from one local branch into another local branch, that's what `git-merge` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour:

`git push -> git push origin -> git push origin :`

`git push origin :` pushes matching branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated **if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side**.

So the branch doesn't exist on remote and it says `Everything up-to-date`

In your list of commands, you have written `git checkout master` - was that supposed to be `mymaster`? Since you seem to be working on mymaster. You have to push like:

`git push origin mymaster`

so that git will create `mymaster` on remote.

Or, since you seem to want to push to master, maybe:

`git push origin mymaster:master`

or

`git push origin HEAD:master`

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#OPTIONS

Comment: > you have written git checkout master - was that supposed to be mymaster?   Indeed, you are correct.  Good catch.  I'm just trying to update master, but thanks for the tidbit on pushing a new remote.  I'm getting it now me thinks!

Answer (score -1):

you are committing to mymaster and trying to push master. That is up to date. If you want to push mymaster to the remote master, do

```
git push origin mymaster:master
```

the form is

```
git push <where> <yourlocalbranch>:<theremotebranch>
```

Comment: helpful, Thanks!  But then what about the "master" branch.. I would need to check it out and pull, with just "get pull" as origin master will be understood, right?  Accept that doesn't work..

Comment: it depends if you want a different named branch to track master. In your case it's "mymaster". There's no point of to having another one called master. Usually that's what one does, but git allows you to have a local branch with a different name when you set up tracking - if you want tracking. Just add the --track option when you push and form then on you can omit the parameters and do `git push`. Why the downvote, btw?

Comment: Whoops!  didn't mean to down vote at all.  Morning eyes.. sigh